# how to remove duplicate array elements in JavaScript and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs3, indexof

I am attempting to set up a Vue demo that prevents a user from inputting duplicate items in an array. The inputs values with the following text field and button:

```
 <div>
    <input v-model="numberValue" type="number" />
 </div>
 <div>
   <button @click="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

After pushing `numberValue.value` into the `numArray` array, I then `for` to loop through the items in numArray. Then, I used the `indexOf` method in a conditional to check for occurances of array items in newArray. If array items don't already exist in newArray, then they will be pushed into newArray.

```
const submit = () => {
  numArray.value.push(numberValue.value)
  
  newArray.value = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numArray.value.length; i++) { 
    if(newArray.value.indexOf(numArray.value[i]) === -1) { 
        newArray.value.push(numArray.value[i]); 
        console.log(newArray.value)
    } else if (newArray.value.indexOf(numArray.value[i]) !== -1) {
      window.alert('No Duplicates Allowed!')
    }
  }
}
```

I then attempted to set up an `else if` statement that targets instances when the user tries to input a duplicate array item. On the else if, I added a window.alert to alert the user when entering a duplicate. After entering a duplicate, I see the alert. I then see the alert on all subsequent inputs, even ones that are not duplicates. How can I go about properly setting up the else if statement to target duplicates and trigger an alert?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this requirement by comparing the input value with `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` values in a `numArray`. And to have non-duplicate values you can use `Set`.

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numberValue: null,
    numArray: []
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.numArray.push(this.numberValue);
      if (this.numArray.indexOf(this.numberValue) !== this.numArray.lastIndexOf(this.numberValue)) {
        alert('No Duplicates Allowed!');
      }
      this.numArray = [...new Set(this.numArray)]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="numberValue" type="number" />
  <button @click="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <br><br>
  {{ numArray }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

before pushing any value into your array, I would verify if the "value" that's being added is already in the array.

```
var existingValue = numArray.find(item => item === numberValue.value)
if (existingValue) {
  window.alert('No Duplicates Allowed!');
  return;
}
numArray.value.push(numberValue.value);
```

If the value does not exist then we can proceed pushing into array

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript set.

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.

Comment: Right, but I wish to set up the ```else if``` statement in that for loop to catch duplicate elements and trigger an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loop use javascript filter option to check whether the element already exist. So that you could restrict the user from making the duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Set you will get unique array.
**In ES6 with the help of Set and ... (spread operator) we can get unique array**

```
newArray.value = [...new Set [numArray?.value]]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The submit function's logic is wrong. For example, debug it by steps as below.

1. enter '5', after `submit()`, `numArray = ['5']`, `newArray = ['5']`
2. enter '5', after `submit()`, `numArray = ['5', '5']`, `newArray = ['5']`, `window.alert()` called.
3. enter '2', `numArray = ['5', '5', '2']`, after fisrt `for` loop, `newArray = ['5']`, after second loop, `window.alert()` called because `numArray[1]` is '5' also.

So you need to do `numArray = newArray.concat()` after `sumbit()` to make `numArray` undunplicated. Otherwise it will trigger alert on all subsequent inputs.